# Unknown Cipher Type '3des' on SSHv1

Tags: networking, ssh

Right now I am having an issue with connecting to a huawei router through SSHv1. Just to let you know, it works with SSHv2, but I need SSHv1 to test some special stuff.

So I open terminal and write:

```
ssh -1 -c 3des user@192.168.0.10
```

I get the message `Unknown cipher type '3des'`, also in the SSH manual this cipher is listed on version 1. I also tried it with DES and blowfish ciphers. Any suggestions?

Here is the log file:

```
root@superuser:~# ssh1 -vvv -1 -c 3des user@192.168.0.10
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug3: kex names ok: [diffie-hellman-group1-sha1]
debug2: resolving "192.168.0.10" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.0.10 [192.168.0.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version -
debug1: no match: -
Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs. 2
```

Comment: So the Router uses only  SSHv2? What do you want to test here?

Comment: I am trying to test different encryption methods on this router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSHv1 is obsolete from current openssh. If you want to use this obsolete protocol, you need to install [`openssh-client-ssh1`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/openssh-client-ssh1) package and use `ssh1` binary, which has still SSHv1 support.

```
ssh1 -1 -c 3des user@192.168.0.10
```

should do the job for you.

Comment: Hey, thanks for reply. I installed openssh-cleint-ssh1 and tried your command but now I get the message "Protocol major versions differ: 1vs. 2"

Comment: Thats weird. Can you post the whole log from `ssh1 -vvv -1 -c 3des user@192.168.0.10` to the edited question?

Comment: Ok forgot to enable SSHv1 on the router. Now it works. Thanks!